# Id token does not contain email when email scope is requested

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have an identity server 4 application and I have added to the email scope [IdentityResources] table in the database.  I have also added the email scope to the client that i am using with my client application.

The client application is now prompting the user for email scope consent after login.

[image]

I can also see that its there in the UserClaimsPrincipalFactory

protected override async Task

```
GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
            if (user.IsXenaSupporter)
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Supporter", user.Id.ToString()));
            return identity;
        }
```

Identity does contain email. Yet when the Id token and access token are returned to the application neither contain an email.   Nor is there an email when i reqeust it from the user info end point.

What do I need to do to populate email address in the claims when the application requests the email scope?  Also my custom supporter claim is also not being added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i had only added it to the [IdentityResources] table.

[image]

This simply defines the different scopes.  But it doesn't actually assign any data.

To do that i needed to add it to the [IdentityClaims] table.

[image]

As soon as i did this the data started being returned in the claims.

Answer (score 0):

The simple fact that the client application is prompting you for the email scope only means, that the scope was allowed in IdentityServer and requested on the client end but not necessarily that this information is being retrieved.

The magic is in the `GetProfileDataAsync` method of your `IProfileService` implementation.

This profile service is where you retrieve whatever claims you'd like and add them to the `ProfileDataRequestContext`.

```
public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    var subjectId = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
    Guid.TryParse(subjectId, out Guid g);

    //whatever way or wherever you retrieve the claims from
    var claimsForUser = idRepo.GetUserClaimsBySubjectId(g);

    context.IssuedClaims = claimsForUser.Select(c => 
        new Claim(c.ClaimType, c.ClaimValue)).ToList();

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

As explained [here](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/14/optimizing-identity-tokens-for-size/), an id token should pretty much only have a sub claim - that's what the `userinfo` endpoint is for.